# Database Explorer option missing in view menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm not able to see "Database Explorer" link in view or view-other menu.

[image]

Rishi

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're looking for the 'Server Explorer' which is on the view menu. The default key binding is Ctrl+Alt+S

Comment: I am not be able to see my db.mdf file in "Server Explorer". Is there any other view that allow me to see that??

Comment: Double click that file **db.mdf** in Solution Explorer. And it will get opened up in **Server Explorer** by own. Might help somebody. I tried in VS 2012 Ultimate.

Comment: After opening "Server Explorer" (Visual Studio 2019) I had to right-click its "Data Connections" then "Add Connection," Microsoft SQL Server (then it had to install components for SQL Server connections--it had to restart so I started over and had to click "Add Connection" again).

Answer (score 6):

It's called "Server Explorer", directly under the View menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Database Explorer" exists only in Visual Studio 2010 **Express**, if you use another edition like Professional or Ultimate it is replaced by more advanced "Server Explorer".